# Inserting data into Mysql with multiple unique keys

Tags: php, mysql

My MYSQL query

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO customers (first_name,last_name,address,city,state,zip,phone,dnc,user_id)
 VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$address','$city','$state','$zip','$phone','$dnc','$userid') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE phone=phone");
```

What I am doing is putting customer information into a database. I Wanted to make sure that each customer was inserted once into the database. This query works for that by using the phone numbers as a unique key. Now the problem I'm having is I want to be able to have duplicates of customers in the database, but no duplicates of customers per user.

In my application multiple users have customers that they have added, but they can't see customer's that other users have added. I want the query to NOT insert only if the user_id and the phone are already in the database. I tried adding

```
 phone=phone AND user_id=$userid
```

to the end of the query but Haven't been able to get it to work right. 
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why don´t you make the combination of phone and user_id UNIQUE index?

Comment: I was thinking of that earlier, do you mean like a string with phone and userid together like phone was 5551231234 and user id is 99 it would be 555123123499?

Comment: nope, you can make one index above multiple columns

Comment: want to give me a little more detail? Not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query to add UNIQUE index above both fields:

```
ALTER TABLE customers ADD UNIQUE `unique_customer` ( user_id , phone)
```

Comment: OK im getting errors, how would i change my query against that?

Comment: I changed the end of the query to     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE unique_lead=unique_lead and Im getting Unknown column 'unique_lead' in 'field list'

Comment: because there is probably no such column :-) You can´t update value of index, just leave it with phone. Or delete the whole ON DUPLICATE KEY statement and handle error in php, it would probably be faster, I´m not sure though

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid, yeah I switched back to  phone=phone after adding unique_customer, works great. Thanks a lot man!